# kafka.errors.UnsupportedCodecError: UnsupportedCodecError: Libraries for snappy compression codec not found while kafka consumer

Tags: python, kafka-consumer-api

Getting below error in message in consumer line

code:

consumer = KafkaConsumer(topic,group_id=groupid,bootstrap_servers=[host])
    for message in consumer:

Error:
    for message in consumer:
  File "*\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kafka\consumer\group.py", line 1192, in **next**
    return self.next_v2()
  File "*\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kafka\consumer\group.py", line 1200, in next_v2
    return next(self._iterator)
  File "*\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kafka\consumer\group.py", line 1115, in _message_generator_v2
    record_map = self.poll(timeout_ms=timeout_ms, update_offsets=False)
  File "*\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kafka\consumer\group.py", line 654, in poll
    records = self._poll_once(remaining, max_records, update_offsets=update_offsets)
  File "*\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kafka\consumer\group.py", line 707, in _poll_once
    records, _ = self._fetcher.fetched_records(max_records, update_offsets=update_offsets)
  File "*\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kafka\consumer\fetcher.py", line 344, in fetched_records
    self._next_partition_records = self._parse_fetched_data(completion)
  File "*\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kafka\consumer\fetcher.py", line 816, in _parse_fetched_data
    unpacked = list(self._unpack_message_set(tp, records))
  File "*\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kafka\consumer\fetcher.py", line 467, in _unpack_message_set
    for record in batch:
  File "*\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kafka\record\legacy_records.py", line 245, in **iter**
    self._buffer = memoryview(self._decompress(key_offset))
  File "*\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kafka\record\legacy_records.py", line 186, in _decompress
    self._assert_has_codec(compression_type)
  File "*Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kafka\record\legacy_records.py", line 126, in _assert_has_codec
    raise UnsupportedCodecError(
kafka.errors.UnsupportedCodecError: UnsupportedCodecError: Libraries for snappy compression codec not found

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please explain what you are trying to do, and provide a sample of the code that is triggering the error.

Answer (score 4):

> UnsupportedCodecError: Libraries for snappy compression codec not found

To consume snappy-compressed messages, you need to [install snappy](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/install.html#optional-snappy-install).

Alternatively, if you control the producer, don't use snappy.

Answer (score 0):

To extend the accepted answer, if you can control the producer, and it is `KafkaProducer`, compression is set by its `compression_type` parameter. You can set it to `'gzip'`, which is available by default in Python, and thus making sure the consumer will have no problem decompressing your message.